# start menu with subfolder

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I use WiX and want to create shortcut in user's start menu like

Start -> [CompanyName] -> [ProgramName] -> App.exe

I can do like

Start -> [ProgramName] -> App.exe

without any problem:

```
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="RoverSoft Test">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>      
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuDir">
  <Component Id="ProgramMenuDirComponent" Guid="{A9858D4C-085A-4132-AD2E-F90A1E5C64A6}">
    <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

But if I add one more level of folders then I get error:
Error   1   ICE64: The directory ProgramMenuSubDir is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.

as I understand, it means, that I should fully clear after a system uninstall (from registry in this case). How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every folder in the user's profile, you'll want to ensure the folder is removed.  So, you can adjust your example like so:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuCompanyDir" Name="Company Name">
       <Directory Id="ProgramMenuProgramDir" Name="ProgramName"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<Component Id="ProgramMenuCompanyDirComponent" Directory='ProgramMenuCompanyDir'>
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name='InstallVersion'
                 Value="[ProductVersion]" Type="string" />
  <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveProgramMenuCompanyDir" On="uninstall" />
</Component>

<Component Id="ProgramMenuProgramDirComponent" Directory='ProgramMenuProgramDir'>
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name='InstallFolder'
                 Value='[INSTALLFOLDER]' Type="string" />
  <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveProgramMenuProgramDir" On="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

That ensures that all the per-user folders have per-user key paths (the registry keys) and are correctly marked to be removed during uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code.

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
      <Directory Id="company" Name="company">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="prod" >
         <Directory Id="INCLUDEDIR" Name="include">
         <Directory Id="THIRDPARTYDIR" Name="3rdParty">
         <Directory Id="BIN" Name="bin"></Directory>

         </Directory>  
        </Directory>
       </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>


 <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="prod">
      <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="0118D11A-0CA3-4E04-8D27-0B73A279A7FD">
        <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
      </Component>

    </Directory>
  </Directory>
 <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"/>
</Directory>
</Fragment>
```

the shortcuts will be like so:

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="comp_bin_debug_30" Guid="EB4650EB-75DC-4562-9DC3-8FFDD9B55468">
    <File Id="file_bin_30" Source="..\bin\Debug.amd64\prod.exe" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" />
      <Shortcut Id="desktopProd" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="prod"
      WorkingDirectory='INSTALLFOLDER' Icon="prod_GUI.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
      <Shortcut Id="startmenuProd" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="prod"
      WorkingDirectory='INSTALLFOLDER' Icon="prod_GUI.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />      
     </Component>
   </DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: it should not work if you have Properties -> Tool Settings -> "Suppress ICE validation" is off. It means that you will not have clear deinstallation.